# How we know calender sync is completed?

Tags: android, events, calendar

I have pragmatically started i sync Google calender evens using following code. But how we know sync is completed or failed

```
    private void requestCalendarSync()
{
    AccountManager aM = AccountManager.get(this);
    Account[] accounts = aM.getAccounts();

    for (Account account : accounts)
    {
        int isSyncable = ContentResolver.getIsSyncable(account,  CalendarContract.AUTHORITY);

        if (isSyncable > 0)
        {
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
            ContentResolver.requestSync(accounts[0], CalendarContract.AUTHORITY, extras);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [SyncStatusObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SyncStatusObserver.html) to get notifications about sync status changes.

Register your observer with the following method:

```
ContentResolver.addStatusChangeListener(ContentResolver.SYNC_OBSERVER_TYPE_ACTIVE, new MySyncStatusObserver());
```

Implement the [onStatusChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SyncStatusObserver.html#onStatusChanged(int)) method:

```
private class MySyncStatusObserver implements SyncStatusObserver {
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(int which) {
        if (ContentResolver.isSyncActive(mAccount, CalendarContract.AUTHORITY)) {
           // There is now an active sync.
        } else {
           // There is no longer an active sync.
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: never executing else part.